# How display Json array to tinymce

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, tinymce

I have json array like this,

```
{
    "kutip":"<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p>",
    "desc":"<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>"
}
```

jquery, script for display value.

```
var data={prodId:prodId};
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    datatype:"json",
    url:"",
    data:data,
    datatype:"html",
    cache:false,
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse( data ); 
        $('#prod_kutip').val(data.kutip);
        $('#prod_desc').val(data.desc);
    }
});
```

But how to display the array to tinymce? I have 2 TinyMCE and how to display and share the array.

Kutip

```
<textarea aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="prod_kutip" name="post_kutip" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Description

```
<textarea aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="prod_desc" name="post_description" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily show the array contents in your tinymce.

In case you want to replace the editor content:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(data);
var editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id'); // id equals your textarea id
editor.setContent(data);
```

In case you want to add the array contents to your editor:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(data);
var editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id'); // id equals your textarea id
editor.execCommand('insertHTML', false, data)
```

Comment: not work, i get TypeError: editor is null editor.execCommand('insertHTML', false, data)

Comment: you have to use your own editor_id. "your_editor_id" is just a placeholder for 'prod_desc' or 'prod_kutip'

Comment: if i use var editor = tinymce.get('#xxxxx'); then the content not set to the editor, and if i use  var editor = window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor; the content set to the editor. how must i use for share the cotent if i use multiple tinymce?

Comment: no, you get an editor instance by id this  way : var editor = tinymce.get('xxxxx'); ('without '#'!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `data = JSON.parse( data );` because `$.ajax` does that already for you. If you want to display the JSON object as a String, you can do this:

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
$('#someElement').val(dataString);
```

Comment: the code is working but i just need the array to show in tinymce,.